# Fusionpbx how to set IVR menu variable

Tags: lua, freeswitch, fusionpbx

I am sorry if this has been asked in Freeswitch or FusionPBX, basically I want to change the VPS to another VPS, and I am getting only FusionPBX 5.10 and currenly I have an FusionPBX 4.5

The problem is I cannot keep the ivr as variable, everytime I save this it goes blank.
I save the code here, and it turns out from the second pic.

Please help.

[image]

[image]